# All divs move by 1 css

Tags: html, css

If i edit the margin-left from 1 div, the form(div) moves also. How can i fix this? I want to have like 3 columns with some text.

```css
#loginwrapper {
  width: 240px;
  height: 305px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 25px;
  background: #8FB0BF;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="loginwrapper">
  <div id="login" align="left">
    <a href="login.php"><input name="naarlogin" type="button" id="loginn_btn" value="Klanten Login" /></a>

    <br></br>
    <a href="register.php"><input name="naarregister" type="button" id="registerr_btn" value="Registreren" /></a>

    <br></br>
    <a href="login.php"><input name="naarlogin" type="button" id="loginn_btn" value="Instructeurs Login" /></a>

    <br></br>
    <a href="register.php"><input name="naarregister" type="button" id="registerr_btn" value="Instructeurs Registreren" /></a>

    <br></br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should provide your html, and all CSS related to it.

Comment: I did edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  understand correctly, you want to edit each DIV individually?
in that case at the moment you can't as the div `id="loginwrapper"` is a div that controls all of your code. if you want to edit input manually give them a class and edit them in css
for example

```css
#loginwrapper {
  width: 240px;
  height: 305px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 25px;
  background: #8FB0BF;
  padding: 5px;
  
}
.input_one{ <----this is the class name of the input (this can be anything you like)
 margin-right: 25px !important
}
```

```html
<div id="loginwrapper">
  <div id="login" align="left">
    <a href="login.php"><input name="naarlogin" type="button" id="loginn_btn" value="Klanten Login" /></a>

    <br></br>
    <a href="register.php"><input  name="naarregister" type="button" id="registerr_btn" value="Registreren" /></a>

    <br></br>
    <a href="login.php"><input name="naarlogin" type="button" id="loginn_btn" value="Instructeurs Login" /></a>

    <br></br>
    <a href="register.php"><input name="naarregister" type="button" id="registerr_btn" value="Instructeurs Registreren" /></a>

    <br></br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The loginwrapper and login are fine atm. I have like this 3 different divs. but when i move the one this one moves also with it when they have nothing to do with each other.